Google Cloud Run - metrics
CPU/Memory usage metrics
I'm trying to read the cpu and memory usage metrics of GCP cloud run and I understand from answer posted in Google Cloud Run: interpreting CPU utilization metrics for concurrency that 99%, 95% and 50% legends mean percentile. But these three show different values at a specific point in time, how can I figure out what is the cpu/memory utilised right now or at any point in time?
I'm trying to create an alert using terraform for my services. I know when my application sends too many tasks rendering my cloud run services to die after sometime. I need to know what was the exact cpu and memory usage at that point of time and it's difficult to figure that out using those three percentiles.


Im assuming that you have HTTP cloud run services. My advice is that you should probably look at 5xx status codes for monitoring the overall health of our service and create alerts on that. If you have crashes due to memory exhaustion or high cpu usage, I would reduce the max concurrency on your service (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency)

Do you have a single instance of your service or do you have multiple instances?

Can you please respond to the above comments by providing the required information.

@guillaumeblaquiere min instance is 1 and max is 10

@TilenKavčič yes they are HTTP cloud run services. Concurrency is limited to 2 using gunicron at the application. But we can use terraform blocks for alerting for gcp: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/terraform
Where I can set threshold value as 0.9 (90%) for cpu usage in condition block  to send email notifs when cpu increases more than 90%.
Can you confirm this 90% is percentage or percentile? Terraform documentation just says: "threshold_value - (Optional) A value against which to compare the time series."
Creating alert based on 5xx code will only notify after crash happens..

Have a look at Link1 and Link2.

Also I tried using cloud monitoring metrics explorer for the memory utilisation, can you tell me what this last line about utilisation is about:

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?

‘Container CPU Utilization’ metric is designed in a way to display the CPU utilization distribution across all the container instances, not for the specific instance. For example you have 3 instances, even though there are 3 container instances running, the time series would display the distribution values across all 3 container instances.
Suppose a Cloud Run service is serving one instance with minimal traffic, in case during the sudden increase in traffic, it will spin up another instance only if the older instance was unable to handle the load, similarly it will spin up the instances according to the load . Hence, the metrics explorer is designed in such a way that it will display the CPU utilization in terms of distribution of the instances CPU utilization.
99%, 95% and 50%, these numbers refer to the distribution metric and distribution-valued metrics, you can find more info about it in this google official document.
For your concern you can have more insights when you can check CPU utilization per instance, but right now there is no feature to check, but there is a feature request raised you can follow.
